# Can you compare strings in python like in Java with .equals?

Tags: python, string, comparison

Can you compare strings in Python in any other way apart from `==`? 
Is there anything like `.equals` in Java?

Comment: `"Hello, World!".__eq__("other string")`. When you use `==` python simply looks up the `__eq__` method of the objects.

Comment: Too easy, you can easily search it on google.


Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to do this.  The first is to use the [`operator`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html) module, which contains functions for all of the mathematical operators:

```
>>> from operator import eq
>>> x = "a"
>>> y = "a"
>>> eq(x, y)
True
>>> y = "b"
>>> eq(x, y)
False
>>>
```

The other is to use the [`__eq__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) method of a string, which is called when you use `==`:

```
>>> x = "a"
>>> y = "a"
>>> x.__eq__(y)
True
>>> y = "b"
>>> x.__eq__(y)
False
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
import operator
a = "string1"
b = "string2"
print operator.eq(a, b)
```

This is similar to Java in that you're not using an explicit operator.

However in Java you're using a method call on the `String` class (i.e., `myString.equals(otherString)`) but in Python `eq` is just a function which you import from a module called `operator` (see [`operator.eq`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.eq) in the documentation).

Answer (score 2):

According to [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html):

> `eq(a, b)` is equivalent to `a == b`

So `==` is just like `.equals` in Java (except it works when the left side is `null`).

The equivalent of Java's `==` operator is the `is` operator, as in:

```
if a is b
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the need for using other than '==' as python strings are immutable and memoized by default?

As pointed in other answers you can use 'is' for reference(id) comparison.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, `.equals()` is used instead of `==`, which checks if they are the same object, not the same value. `.equals()` is used for comparing the actual values of 2 strings.

However, in Python, "==" by default checks if they have the same value so it is better to use in general.

As other solutions pointed out, you can also `__eq__` as another way to get the same result.